# What does this drummer use to get this electronic sound

Tags: drums, electronic-drumset

Throught [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6ZhKYr5QH4) video, the drummer can be seen using some sort of electronic pad that creates a clap sound, e.g. at 1:02. I am new to electronic drums and would like to know what is the exact name of what he is using.

I would be really grateful if someone could point out the exact product he is using. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He's using a couple pads from an electronic drumset, like these:

[image]

The pads are then connected to an electronic drum module, like this:

[image]

The drum module is what produces the specific sounds. And there are a variety of brands and models in different price ranges so you should be able to find something within your budget. Roland is a great brand for electronic drums and modules. Check out local music stores which have electronic drum kits you can try out and also look on youtube for demonstration videos so you can hear how different modules sound before you decide on one.

Comment: Thank you very much! I noticed that the drum module you suggested is a little bit out of my budget (I am looking something for under 300 usd). Can you recommend me something cheaper that can serve the same purpose?

Comment: The DDrum DD1 module goes for $200 new, but I don't have any experience with it. A local music store might have it so you can try it out in person to make sure it'll work for you. If you're willing to buy used then you could check out ebay and/or craigslist and you might find a good deal on a more expensive module.

Comment: If you have a Mac, GarageBand has a bunch of freely available electronic drumsets (known as "drum machines") as software instruments.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Tekkerue's answer, electronic drum modules (my Yamaha works well, and wasn't expensive: the joys of second hand) have MIDI ports, so can be wired to other sound modules to give just about any sound on earth, using the drums as triggers, which is, after all, what they are. Rather like a lot of synthesisers and work stations make drum sounds when keys are pressed, but the other way about.